# How do I connect to the PredictIt API (type application/xml) using PHP/CURL?

Tags: php, xml, curl, web-applications

This code is not returning anything:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array('Contect-Type: application/xml', 'Accept: application/xml');
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/ticker/RNOM16',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<p>Data</p>';
print_r($data);
?>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The code is running fine. `$data` is populated with proper XML response from https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/ticker/RNOM16 API. Turn on error reporting or take a look into PHP logs to check for errors

Comment: I did check the logs, nothing out of the ordinary.  $data is not returning anything, either with print(), print_r() or echo().  Thanks.

Comment: In that case most probably you are getting `false` result from `curl_exec` method you can replace `print` with `var_dump($data)` to check it. To be able to get more info why you are getting `false` use `curl_getinfo` or `curl_error`

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it fixed.  Since I'm on cheap shared webhosting, had to contact tech support to get them to update PHP & OpenSSL from a years-old version.